# Whats wrong with my formula?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm using this formula in SharePoint for "*Level of Risk*":

```
=IF([MultipleFunctional]<6;"LOW";IF([MultipleFunctional]<10;"MEDIUM";IF([MultipleFunctional]<20;"HIGH";IF([MultipleFunctional]>20;"CRITICAL";"
```

It works correctly, but if "*MultipleFunction*" is 20 the formula breaks and putting zero instead of critical - why does this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have added incomplete formula in your question.

Anyway, use this formula for your calculated column:

```
=IF([MultipleFunctional]<6;"LOW";IF([MultipleFunctional]<10;"MEDIUM";IF([MultipleFunctional]<20;"HIGH";"CRITICAL")))
```

Comment: Thank you, it works!